# how to write database level validation for numericality max and min value of an integer column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to write a validation for ensuring the minimum and maximum value of an integer column.

I know I can use the [helpers of the numericality validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality) as follow:

```
  validates :column_name, numericality: { 
                                  only_integer: true,
                                  greater_than: 0,
                                  less_than:    100
                                }
```

My question however, is that if I want to give a database level validation for this, how can I go about it

PS: I'm using Postgres.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [domain](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createdomain.html); something like:

```
CREATE DOMAIN something AS INT CHECK (VALUE BETWEEN 1 AND 99)
```

and then declare the table column as the type `something`.